# Storing variables in my name spaced javascript

Tags: javascript

If I have my name space for my app like so:

```
var myApp = {};

(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };
}).apply(myApp);
```

Then if I log the following result:

```
console.log(myApp.next()); //1
```

How can I store variable within the name space function, for instance something like:

```
var myApp = {};

(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };

    // Store variables here ...
    this.variableStore = function() {
            var var1 = "One";
    };
}).apply(myApp);
```

Trying to access like this:

```
console.log(myApp.variableStore().var1); // Gives me an error
```

Is this possible, or even a good idea? Or should I just declare a new name space for what are essentially global variables?

Answer (score 2):

```
var myApp = {};

(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };

    // Store variables here ...
    this.variableStore = function() {
            this.var1 = "One";
            return this;
    };
}).apply(myApp);
```

Such declaration will add `var1` property to `myApp` object only after `variableStore()` is called:

```
myApp.var1 //undefined
myApp.variableStore() // Object {...}
myApp.var1 //"One"
```

About your question: you can not actually store variable within a function. If you are trying to make a internal namespace for myApp, consider doing the following:

```
(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };

    this.subNameSpace = {
        init: function () {
            this.var1 = "One"
            return this;
        }
    }
}).apply(myApp);
myApp.subNameSpace.init();
myApp.subNameSpace.var1; //"One"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function() {
    var id = 0, var1; //DECLARE VARIABLE HERE
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };

    // Store variables here ...
    this.variableStore = function() {
            this.var1 = "One"; //NO "VAR" KEYWORD
    };
}).apply(myApp);
```

Using `var var1 = "One";` creates `var1` in the *local* scope, so you can't access it from the instance of `myApp`. Also, remember to use `this.var1`; otherwise the variable `var1` is essentially a private variable and can't be accessed from the outside.

Also, if you want to use

```
console.log(myApp.variableStore().var1);
```

Then you'll have to `return myApp;` in your `variableStore` method. This is because `myApp.variableStore()` currently returns nothing, so you can't access `var1` of nothing. So, here is the complete code:

```
var myApp = {};
(function() {
    var id = 0, var1;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };

    // Store variables here ...
    this.variableStore = function() {
            this.var1 = "One";
            return myApp;
    };
}).apply(myApp);
console.log(myApp.variableStore().var1);
```

Comment: If he was to return `this` in `variableStore`, he still wouldn't be able to do `variableStore().var1`, as `var1` isn't a property on `this`.

Comment: @Matt Oh, oops. Editing now

Answer (score 1):

You already got some answers on how you could use your `variableStore` function. But maybe it would be sufficient for you to just store your variable with the `.`-operator?

```
var myApp = {};

(function() {
    var id = 0;
    this.next = function() {
        return id++;  
    };
}).apply(myApp);

//store:
myApp.var1 = "One";

//request:
console.log(myApp.var1); //One
```